# What to conclude from $ x \in (A \setminus B \cap B \setminus C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification

I have been working on one of the proof of logical statement and one part of it is like this:

$ x \in (A \triangle B) \cap (B \triangle C)$

$ x \in (A \setminus  B\cup B \setminus A) \cap (B \setminus C \cup C \setminus B)$

$x \in (A \setminus B \cap (B \setminus C \cup C \setminus B)) \cup (B \setminus A \cap (B \setminus C \cup C \setminus B)$

$x \in ((A \setminus B \cap B \setminus C) \cup (A \setminus B \cap C \setminus  B)) \cup ((B \setminus A \cap B \setminus C) \cup (B \setminus A \cap C \setminus B))$

Now let us consider one of the disjunct:

$ x \in (A \setminus B \cap B \setminus C)$

Now from the above it follows that $x \in B$ and $x \notin B$. So I get a contradictory result from it. How does it affect the whole logical expression ?

Does that mean that I can ignore it in the $x \in ((A \setminus B \cap B \setminus C) \cup (A \setminus B \cap C \setminus  B))$ and only consider $x \in (A \setminus B \cap C \setminus  B))$ in my proof ?

Comment: Yes, since $A \setminus B \cap B \setminus C = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

Let X={x| $x\in{A}$ ; $x\notin{B}$}

Let Y={x|$x\in{B}$ ; $x\notin{C}$}

Then it is clear that the intersection of x and y is the empty set.  An element cannot be missing from B and also present in B simultaneously.

Now, what does it mean to form a union between the empty set and some other set A?

Answer (score 0):

In pure reference to proofs, you want to provide ALL intermediate steps. Hence if a necessary operational step is done to the logical expression, you must add it.

Referring to your question involving $x\in{B}$ and $ x\notin{B}$ in the initial expression, **hint:** think about the meaning for which $A\backslash{B}$ and $B\backslash{C}$ are in the expression with respect to the universal set $H$ ($\{A,B,C,\ldots\}$). The notation as given:

$$A\backslash{B}=\{x\in{H}:x\in{A} \ \text{and} \ x\notin{B}\},$$

$$B\backslash{C}=\{x\in{H}:x\in{B} \ \text{and} \ x\notin{C}\}.$$